# Test if a Java Interface has been Proxied

Tags: java

Is there a simple way through reflections to test if a Java interface has been proxied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Proxy.isProxyClass()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#isProxyClass%28java.lang.Class%29)

```
Proxy.isProxyClass(yourInterface.getClass())
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the implementation: Check `this.getClass().getName()` for generic names or `this.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Class<?>)` if you have a specific proxy in mind.

`Proxy.isProxyClass()` might also help (depending on the method used for implementing the proxy.

Comment: Just curious in which circumstances `Proxy.isProxyClass()` will not help?